# What are the parameters sent to .fail in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can’t find the documentation on what the names of the three parameters are when `$.ajax` fails.

Right now, I’m just using:

```js
.fail(function(A, B, C) {
```

Comment: Likely the same that are passed to the `error` callback: `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ the `fail` callback should be getting:

`jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`

same as `error`, but `error` is deprecated:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't notice. Thanks for sharing that piece of the documentation. I'm glad jQuery XHR callbacks are finally matching up with Deferreds.

Comment: Oh, but the ajaxError method has event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError.

Comment: They are all the same callback that get passed the same arguments, just different uses and contexts.

Comment: Where does it state that the fail callback gets these 3 arguments? It also states so for the complete setting parameter. These are different, e.g. the arguments to `complete` are different than the arguments passed to `done`.

Comment: @Tom, I know I'm way late to respond to you but it is stated here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR  (`jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});`)

Comment: Thanks the jQuery documentation seems to be missing this!

Answer (score 36):

Here an example after looking for the same problem:

```
this.GetOrderList = function (customerId) {
    var self = this;
    $.post('MySuperServer.aspx', { customerId: customerId })
    .done(function (dataStr) {
        var orderList = jQuery.parseJSON(dataStr);
        self.process(orderList);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Post error: " + error);
    });
}
```

While debugging, I've got:

- *jqXHR* is a JS object
- *textStatus* is "error"
- *error* is "Internal Server Error", it's the error message sent by the server.

Comment: Yeah, I think what they're trying to connote by using the word textStatus is that this is the status variable and that it's in text format. As compared to jqXHR, which is a jQuery object.