# Cross domain JSON request failing to populate elements

Tags: jquery

I have a web API that returns a JSON string as such:

```
{"TipString":"Some text value here","TipNumber":"005"}
```

I need to push the `TipString` and `TipNumber` values into two paragraph tags:

```
<p id="n"></p>
<p id="s"></p>
```

From my searching today I've created the following code to achieve this, but it isn't working:

**UPDATED**

```
$.getJSON(tipUrl)
.done(function (json) {
    $('#n').text(json["tipNumber"]);
    $('#s').text(json["tipString"]);
})
.fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + errorThrown;
    $('#s').text(err);
});
```

This is a cross-domain request, and I know there is some issues with this being allowed, however, I can see that in Firebug the JSON string is being returned.
However, in the page I only see `error,` being populated.  Is my approach wrong, or my syntax??

Comment: cross-domain shouldn't be an issue if you are only retrieving JSON data. What is the error message?

Comment: According to your `done` function it takes `json` argument, so what is the `data` then?

Comment: Just as @Pavlo said, try to replace `json` with `data` in your second line.

Comment: Thanks.  Please see my comments in the answer below

Comment: @EvilDr Make sure your **[.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)** function is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax.

```
 $.getJSON(tipUrl)
  .done(function (json) {
       $('#n').text(json["tipNumber"]);
       $('#s').text(json["tipString"]);
  })
  .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
      var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
      $('#s').text(err);
  });
```

Changed data => json in the Done function

Comment: I've just seen that `error` is deprecated - use `errorThrown` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9847328/792888 I've updated the question as the error still occurs but `errorThrown` is blank

Comment: you didn't mention id="tipString". change the field ID accordingly.

Comment: Oh no sorry that's my mistake.  I forgot to simplify the code.  Even when changed it doesn't work.  Sorry for the confusion (deleting earlier comment).

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere.  When I run in IE, debugger shows this `XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.` which I think is a port number issue (I omitted port number from URL - it is a different port number).

Comment: Yes, I need JSONP to fix this problem.  Accepting this as the answer as it fixed the syntax error which allowed me to investigate further.  Thank you.