# Laravel, return response 400 error with jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I built a web system months ago using Laravel 4.1 and in my requests I used Response::json(); to return data to jquery ajax.

- 200 to return a success and catched by .done() of ajax.
- 400 to return a fail/error and catched by .fail() of ajax.

And works very good!

The problem now, I'm building another web system with Laravel 4.2 and I'm using the same error codes 200 and 400... 200 works fine but 400 not working because for example:

**Laravel**

```
<?php

    public function example()
    {
        if (Input::get('param1') === 'value1') {
            return Response::json(array(
                'msg' => 'Correct!' 
            ), 200);
        }

        return Response::json(array(
            'msg' => 'Incorrect!'
        ), 400);
    }
?>
```

**jQuery** (I'm using the same jquery version: 1.10.2)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data.msg);
})
.fail(function(data) {
    console.log(data.msg);
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

I both cases, the request return the json correctly but...

When is Correct/200, .done() of ajax displays the message correctly in console but if it's Incorrect/400, .fail() of ajax not display the message but display **undefined** and I don't know what happend.

I hope you can help me.

**Solved**

Check my self-answer.

Comment: what if you just log out `data` itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved**

I can receive the json on fail using this:

```
fail(function(jqXHR)) {
      console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON.msg);
}
```

And works fine!

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is that, according to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), your data isn't actually sent to the `fail` function:

> jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
>   An alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail() method replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to deferred.fail() for implementation details.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847244/what-are-the-parameters-sent-to-fail-in-jquery).

If you want to get around this and still be able to send some data back to the client in the event of failure, a workaround could be to always return a 200 response but include a `'success'` parameter indicating whether the operation was successfully completed or not and just handle everything inside of the `done` callback.

Comment: Yes is true, but I found a solution: I can use the jqXHR parameter in fail() function and get the json element using. jqXHR.responseJSON.msg and works!

Comment: congrats! you should probably go ahead and add that as a self-answer then to help others coming back later