# JSON fails in Javascript but POSTMAN works

Tags: jquery, json, botframework

This works from postman but the Javascript fails everytime!
Any know what I've done wrong?

The code sample comes from here https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a073d9e041ad42d9ba9

```
    $(function() {
        var params = {     
        }; 
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/dfb79d2e-4f4d-4201-8511-b9d7ab08bcb1/generateAnswer?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);
            },
            type : "POST",
            data : {"question" : "Hi"}
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        alert("Post error: " + error);
    });
});
```

--Console Log ---

> POST XHR
>   https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/dfb79d2e-4f4d-4201-8511-b9d7ab08bcb1/generateAnswer [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 377ms] Headers Params POST Response Call
>   Stack
>   ErrorObjectCode"BadArgument"Message"[{"Key":"query","Value":[""]}]"
>   {"Error":{"Code":"BadArgument","Message":"[{\"Key\":\"query\",\"Value\":[\"\"]}]"}}

Comment: "fails" is a bit vague - do you get an error message in the console?  do you get the fail() callback?  What's the `textStatus` value in fail (which you don't have in your code snippet) ?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9847328/2181514

Comment: the fail is "Post error: Bad Request"

Comment: Are you sure your `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` is supposed to be public knowledge?

Comment: I actually, after a couple of hours, I was able to make it work :)

Comment: Haha... what did you do Hackerman ??

Comment: You can check my answer :)

Comment: If this answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **After a lot of trial and error, I was able to make it work; just for the record
>   the Microsoft documentation on the subject, is not working.**

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/dfb79d2e-4f4d-4201-8511-b9d7ab08bcb1/generateAnswer",
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","theKey");
        },
        type : "POST",
        data : {"question": "Hi"},
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    });
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e28gn17g/1/)</kbd>